# RESTful service - using Phil Sturgeon Rest Server : Logic / function for validating the users with their username and password?

Tags: php, rest

I'm writing a simple RESTful service, using Phil Sturgeon Rest Server. Can anyone provide me a solution for login using username and password. I am able to get all the json reponse without login.

**Porblem 1** : `$config['rest_auth'] = 'basic';`

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> The configuration file ldap.php does not exist.
>
> The same happens with `$config['rest_auth'] = 'digest';`

I haven't used "ldap" earlier and don't know how it works apart from a few basic information. So could you please tell me what could be the reason for this error ?

> **Tried out Solutions**
>
> I changed the value of `$config['auth_source'] = 'ldap';` to `$config['auth_source'] = '';` , Now REST Login Usernames are working for both basic and digest , ie;

`$config['rest_auth'] = 'basic';` or `$config['rest_auth'] = 'digest';`.

```
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = ['admin' => '1234','sudheesh'=>'test'];
```

> **Prevailing issue :** unable to use **session** for authentication

Tried the commented notes from Phil Sturgeon ie;

> Note: If 'rest_auth' is set to 'session' then change 'auth_source' to
>   the name of the session variable

**How the session is created in MODEL, it is here  :**

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            // If there is a user, then create session data
            $row = $query->row();
            $data = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'name' => $row->full_name,
                'email' => $row->email,
                'phone' => $row->phone,
                'acc_status' => $row->rec_status,
                'validated' => true

            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            //$this->session->set_authkey('1e957ebc35631ab22d5bd6526bd14ea2');
            //print_r($data);
            return $data;
```

**Question is :** How can I change the 'auth_source' to
 the name of the session variable ,

> Right now it is `$config['auth_source'] = ''`
>
> Do i have to change it to : `$config['validated']` , if I do this am not getting the access , I have read [here](http://pythonhackers.com/p/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) that:
>
> If you're tying this library into an AJAX endpoint where clients
>   authenticate using PHP sessions then you may not like either of the
>   digest nor basic authentication methods. In that case, you can tell
>   the REST Library what PHP session variable to check for. If the
>   variable exists, then the user is authorized. It will be up to your
>   application to set that variable. You can define the variable in
>   `$config['auth_source']`. Then tell the library to use a php session
>   variable by setting `$config['rest_auth']` to `session`.

Is there any suggestions ?

**Problem 2** : How can I grant API access to users with a valid username and password ?

> Can anyone provide me with a function or detailed information on how to implement this ?

**Other Doubts** :

> `$config['rest_valid_logins'] = ['admin' => '1234'];`

The description for this 'REST Login Usernames' says if ldap is configured this is ignored.

***Question*** : How can I use this Array of usernames and passwords for login, without configuring LDAP.

> REST Login Class and Function

This says,  If library authentication is used define the class and function name. 
The function should accept two parameters: `class->function($username, $password)`.
In other cases override the function _perform_library_auth in your controller.

For digest authentication the library function should return already a stored md5(username:restrealm:password) for that username.

e.g: md5('admin:REST API:1234') = '1e957ebc35631ab22d5bd6526bd14ea2'

```
$config['auth_library_class'] = '';
$config['auth_library_function'] = '';
```

**Question:** Can I use this to allow users with a valid username and password to access the API ? If Yes , Do you have any functions already written to help in this scenario , any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much . 
If you know answers for any of my issues, please help. Thanks again.

Comment: There seem to be quite some questions in here... one post one question please.

Comment: Ok, I will be careful from now onwards. Thank you. Since all are related and if someone else is having the same issues in the future , I thought this would be helpful .

Comment: REST services does not use login or server side sessions because it would violate the stateless constraint.

Comment: I am trying to create a web service from an existing codeigniter project for a mobile app. Logins or access tokens have to provided and is there is any solution for that ?

Comment: Most APIs work by providing a resource that gives the consumer a secret token in exchange for valid credentials.  The consumer must then submit the token with each subsequent request to prove their authorization.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempt to address every single question posted by Sudheesh, I would like to propose an alternate solution.

Disclaimer: This is a commercial Joomla plugin, so please keep that in mind before proceeding...

Having experienced the same challenge as yourself, I ended up building a RESTful API framework for Joomla, powered by the Slim PHP micro-framework. This allowed me to leverage all the power of Slim, including it's standards-compliant routing architecture, request-type handling and much, much more. This also solved the problem of deal with authentication, access control, content management, database access, etc. because it runs on the Joomla CMS & Platform framework.

This solution provides exactly what you are looking for, easily extensible through plugins and is built on an already popular and well support RESTful API framework (Slim).

For more information on the micro-framework I used:

http://slimframework.com

For more information on the Joomla RESTful API package:

http://getcapi.org

What does it provide?

- Control Panel for managing access tokens, API rate limitation and other Slim parameters
- Pluggable framework allowing for easy incorporation of new web service routes (include new ones to be released soon, for MySQL, MSSQL, LDAP, etc.)
- Based on Joomla. This means you don't have to worry about writing the authentication, access control, content management or other framework. It's already done!

Examples of how username and password can be passed through to create a logged in session via a URL request:

GET user/login/:username/:password

"User login authentication via Joomla authentication plugins with username and password. Note that since credentials are passed into the URL, be aware that they can be stored in server logs. API traffic must traverse a secure (HTTPS) connection."

Response: JSON

Example request:

GET https://yourdomain.com/api/v1/user/login/dynus.borvalds/3jf9LfjNdiw

Example response:

```
{"msg": "Authenticated","jresponse": true,"session":"1a36eab5e2b102a979918ee049f15e27","error": false,"status": 200}
```

The session ID can then be used to force log-out for that session using the method:

GET user/logout/:user/:session

Hope this gets you pointed in the right direction. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15606297)

Comment: Thanks for following up SamT. I can provide additional detail if needed.