# CodeIgniter + RESTfull server throws 400 response when requesting user

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I'm working on tutorial [Working with RESTful Services in CodeIgniter](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814) and i have problem with one line of code.
In `user_get()` function condition `if(!$this->get('id'))` throws 400 response if i try to get resource `http://localhostApp/api/user/1`

What am I missing out?
Do i request resources wrong way?

This is my Api controller:

```
    class Api extends REST_Controller
    {
        function user_get(){
            if(!$this->get('id')){ //Problem line
                $this->response(NULL, 400);
            }
            $user = $this->user_model->get( $this->get('id') );
            if($user){
                $this->response($user, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
            }else{
                $this->response(NULL, 404);
            }
        }

        function user_post(){
            $result = $this->user_model->update( $this->post('id'), array(
                'name' => $this->post('name'),
                'email' => $this->post('email')
            ));

            if($result === FALSE){
                $this->response(array('status' => 'failed'));
            }else{
                $this->response(array('status' => 'success'));
            }

        }

        function users_get(){
            $users = $this->user_model->get_all();

            if($users){
                $this->response($users, 200);
            }else{
                $this->response(NULL, 404);
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

If you need any additional info, please let me know.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass data to `user_get()`, You have to define it in your URL.

> `http://localhostApp/api/user/1`

In here you define  `user`. but there is no any id passed to call which user

So your URL should be

> `http://localhostApp/api/user/id/1`
>
> **Note:** Don't Just copy and paste code from that site to your project. Change it to as your need

Comment: HI!
I'm trying this code just to see how it's working, then i will write my own.

if i try your request http://localhostApp/api/user_get/1
i get response
{
    "status": false,
    "error": "Unknown method."
}
as far as i know, this rest controller automatically knows that you are calling user resource and adds GET/POST/.... by it self based on your request

Comment: There is example on tutorial:
$this->get()
Is used to return GET variables from either a query string like this index.php/example_api/user?id=1 or can be set in the more CodeIgniter'esque way with index.php/example_api/user/id/1.

Comment: inside api folder, it contains some files and details did you place it to yours ??

Comment: Yes i have rest.php inside config
And i have added two file libraries.
If i write my own method to fetch all users via API then it's working,
even if i modify this method to not check if argument is passed, it's working. So i'm only searching for explanation why !$this->get('id') works in his source code and not in mine

Comment: in there i think id is set. but in your method you doesn't have id with value.

Comment: Yes i crack it! I had to chage my controller function a little bit, then call my resource this way.
http://localhostApp/api/user/id/1

You can change you answer this way and i will market it as correct answer

Comment: @DavorBramorPečnik happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have been using the RESTful service - using Phil Sturgeon Rest Server.

Used POST instead of GET for retrieving the user details

**routes.php**

```
$route['api/view/user_details'] = 'api/view/user_details';
```

**Form for testing :**

```
<form class="form-horizontal inline" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>api/view/user_details" method="post">
        <label for="user_id">Enter User ID</label>
        <input id="user_id" type="text" name="id" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**Controller Method** for returning the user information in JSON

```
public function user_details_post()
{


    $id = $this->post('id');

    $this->load->model('admin_model');

    $users = $this->admin_model->view_clients();



    // If the id parameter doesn't exist return all the users

    if ($id == NULL)
    {
        // Check if the users data store contains users (in case the database result returns NULL)
        if ($users)
        {
            // Set the response and exit
            $this->response(['all_users'=>$users], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); // OK (200) being the HTTP response code
        }
        else
        {
            // Set the response and exit
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'message' => 'No users were found'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); // NOT_FOUND (404) being the HTTP response code
        }
    }

    // Find and return a single record for a particular user.

    $id = (int) $id;

    // Validate the id.
    if ($id <= 0)
    {
        // Invalid id, set the response and exit.
        $this->response(NULL, REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST); // BAD_REQUEST (400) being the HTTP response code
    }

    // Get the user from the array, using the id as key for retreival.
    // Usually a model is to be used for this.

    $user = NULL;

    if (!empty($users))
    {
        foreach ($users['user_details'] as $key => $value)
        {
            if (isset($value['id']) && $value['id'] === $id)
            {
                $user = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($user))
    {
        $this->set_response([
            'user_details'=>$user], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); // OK (200) being the HTTP response code
    }
    else
    {
        $this->set_response([
            'status' => FALSE,
            'message' => 'User could not be found'
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); // NOT_FOUND (404) being the HTTP response code
    }

}
```

**MODEL:** Returning an array of users with all details to the controller

```
public function view_clients()
    {

        $result=$this->db->get('clients');

        $results=array();

        foreach ($result->result() as $row)
        {
            $id = $row->id;
            $id = (int) $id;
            $results[] = array(
                'id' => $id,
                'full_name' => $row->full_name,
                'gender' => $row->gender,
                'email' => $row->email,
                'dob' => $row->dob,
                'phone' => $row->phone,
                'address' => $row->address,
                'username' => $row->username,
                'country' => $row->country,
                'city' => $row->city,
                'rec_status' => $row->rec_status,
                'crt_date' => $row->crt_date,
                'email_ver_status' => $row->email_ver_status,
                'mobile_ver_status' => $row->mobile_ver_status,
            );
            $return_array= array("status:" =>'success',
                "user_details" => $results );

        }

        return($return_array);
    }
```

Response am getting as JSON for the POST request with ID

```
{
    "user_details": {
        "id": 1,
        "full_name": "sudheesh sudhakaran",
        "gender": "Male",
        "email": "mails2sudheesh@gmail.com",
        "dob": "12\/03\/1986",
        "phone": "0567462013",
        "address": "kottayil house po kundaliyoor\r\nthrissur",
        "username": "sudheesh",
        "country": "India",
        "city": "KERALA",
        "rec_status": "A",
        "crt_date": "",
        "email_ver_status": null,
        "mobile_ver_status": null
    }
}
```

> To fetch the record of all users , POST a NULL value.

The Questions asked while creating this are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931342/restful-service-using-phil-sturgeon-rest-server-logic-function-for-validat)